# Codeigniter pagination routing issue

Tags: codeigniter, pagination, routes

I have configured a route in routes.php  as,

```
$route['job-history/(:num)'] = "customer/customer/jobhistory/$1";
```

and pagination configuration in controller as follows,

```
$this->load->library('pagination');
$config['per_page'] = 25;
$config['total_rows'] = 100;
$config['base_url'] = $this->config->item('base_url').'job-history';
$config["uri_segment"] = 2;
$this->pagination->initialize($config);
$page = ($this->uri->segment(2)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;
```

Its showing 404 error page while loading,

www.example.com/job-history

It will work if manually add a zero like www.example.com/job-history/0.

How can I load  www.example.com/job-history as first page. Whats wrong in my confuration. Any help please

Comment: @Cryode is correct. You can try to combine both routes into a single route by using `$route['job-history(/:num)?'] = 'customer/customer/jobhistory$1';` I didn't test it, but give it a try.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You'll need a route for the single `job-history` segment as well.

```
$route['job-history/(:num)'] = 'customer/customer/jobhistory/$1';
$route['job-history'] = 'customer/customer/jobhistory';
```

Answer (score 2):

Since, in route.php, you have only mentioned for job-history pages that has a number segment after it and there is no such rule for your page job-history only, it gets redirected to 404.

Add

```
$route['job-history'] = 'customer/customer/jobhistory';
```

before

```
$route['job-history/(:num)'] = 'customer/customer/jobhistory/$1';
```